Center elements based on different scales
The central menu item is well centered in full-screen mode in my browser and with my screen sizes. However, even with a small change in size, the elements stop centering correctly, especially the radial menu. And I need them to be centered strictly relative to the svg element, and preferably not to increase with decreasing size. That is, ideally they behaved like a vector (svg).
Normal position:

wrong position:

mobile version:


Here is the code (html+css):


#F {
  transform: translate(0%, 2%);
}

#border {
  transform: translate(0%, -2%);
}

body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-open-button {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1vh solid #9D9E99;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  left: 50%;
  top: 84vh;
  position: fixed;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
  transition: transform ease-out 200ms;
  transition: transform ease-out 200ms, -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
}

.menu-open-button:hover {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background: #379;
  border: 1vh solid #FFFFFF;
}

.menu-open-button:hover .lines {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu-open {
  display: none;
}

.lines {
  width: 5vh;
  height: 0.7vh;
  background: #9D9E99;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -2.4vh;
  margin-top: -0.3vh;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
  transition: transform 200ms;
  transition: transform 200ms, -webkit-transform 200ms;
}

.line-1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -1.7vh, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -1.7vh, 0);
}

.line-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.line-3 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1.7vh, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 1.7vh, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button .line-1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button .line-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button .line-3 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu-open-button {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

.menu-open-button:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  border-color: transparent;
}

.cssplay-menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 42.5vw;
  top: 50vh;
  width: 40vh;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transform: translateX(-850%) z-index:1;
}

.hover {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  left: 45vw;
  margin-top: 84vh;
  position: fixed;
}

.hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #379;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-out, background-color 0.5s ease-out, top 0.5s ease-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

#menu-open:checked~.hover::before {
  top: -600%;
  transform: scale(3500);
  /* Увеличивает круг, чтобы он покрывал экран */
  background-color: #379;
}

.cssplay-menu .holder {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  max-width: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  --mask: radial-gradient(#0000 34.65%, #ffff 34.95% 67.5%, #0000 67.8% 69.5%, #ffff 69.7%);
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask) no-repeat;
  mask: var(--mask) no-repeat;
  mask-position: 0 20vh;
  mask-size: 100% auto;
}

.cssplay-menu input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.cssplay-menu .segment {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  margin-left: -48%;
  margin-top: -48%;
  width: 96%;
  height: 96%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 2.4, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.menu-open:checked~.segment {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.cssplay-menu .curve-upper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  top: 1%;
  width: 98%;
  height: 98%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0s;
}

.cssplay-menu .curve-lower {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(-240deg) scale(0);
  transition: 0s;
}

.cssplay-menu .curve {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #8b0000;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(60deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #008080;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  transition: 0.25s ease;
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(-230deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(-200deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(-170deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotate(-140deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotate(-110deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) skewY(60deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(7) {
  transform: rotate(100deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(8) {
  transform: rotate(140deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(9) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .center {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -20%;
  margin-top: -20%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #8b0000;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu .holder .segment {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu .holder .center {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu .holder .curve-upper {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu .holder .curve-lower {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform: rotate(-240deg) scale(1);
}

.cssplay-menu #c1:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(1),
.cssplay-menu #c2:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(2),
.cssplay-menu #c3:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(3),
.cssplay-menu #c4:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(4),
.cssplay-menu #c5:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(5),
.cssplay-menu #c6:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(6),
.cssplay-menu #c7:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(7),
.cssplay-menu #c8:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(8),
.cssplay-menu #c9:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(9) {
  background: #eb8c00;
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu #c2:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-210deg)
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu #c3:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-180deg)
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu #c4:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-150deg)
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu #c5:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-120deg)
}

body[data-or-condition="1"] {
  #M0 {
    height: 300vh !important;
  }
  .cssplay-menu {
    transform: translate(0%, 252%);
    z-index: 4;
  }
  .menu-open-button {
    transform: translate(0%, 830%);
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .hover {
    margin-top: 180vh;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  #menu-open:checked~.hover::before {
    top: 300%;
  }
  .menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate(0%, 1030%);
    transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate(0%, 1030%);
    transition: 0 ease;
  }
  .p1 {
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translate(-3%, 102%);
  }
  .p2 {
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translate(-3.5%, 140%);
  }
  .p3 {
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translate(-4%, 190%);
  }
  g[id="p2"] {
    display: none;
  }
  g[id="p3"] {
    display: none;
  }
  g[id="border"] {
    display: none;
  }
}
<html>

<head>
  <title>Techonology</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body class="no-scroll" id="TL" style="" data-or-condition="0">
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background: #379;">

    <div id="M0" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open" id="menu-open"></input>
        <label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
        <span class="lines line-1"></span>
        <span class="lines line-2"></span>
        <span class="lines line-3"></span>
    </label>
        <label class="hover"></label>
        <div class="cssplay-menu">
          <div>
            <input type="radio" id="c1" name="segment" checked="checked">
            <input type="radio" id="c2" name="segment">
            <input type="radio" id="c3" name="segment">
            <input type="radio" id="c4" name="segment">
            <input type="radio" id="c5" name="segment">
            <input type="checkbox" id="c6" onclick="checkConditions()">
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" checked="checked">
            <div class="holder">
              <div class="segment">
                <label for="c1"><span></span></label>
                <label for="c2"><span></span></label>
                <label for="c3"><span></span></label>
                <label for="c4"><span></span></label>
                <label for="c5"><span></span></label>
                <label for="c6"><span></span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="curve-lower">
                <div class="curve"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <svg id="M1" class="page_1" version="1.1" height="100vh" width="100vw" viewBox="0 0 1280 960">
        <g id="F">
                <g id="border">
                    <path d="M1 1 l0 950 l2 -2 l0 -946 l1270 0 l2 -2 Z" fill="#9DAACA" id="3DB"></path>
                    <path d="M1275 951 l0 -950 l-2 2 l0 946 l-1270 0 l-2 2 Z" fill="#6A7489" id="3DS"></path>
                </g>
        </g>        
 </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




I've edited your question to convert the posted HTML and CSS into a working [snippet] so that your problem can be easily reproduced in the question. The syntax highlighting in the editor (when editing the question) suggests that you have a mismatch in opening and closing tags, the </div> before the closing <body> is highlighted red; typically this means you've either left a tag open that should've been closed, or removed a closing tag by accident. Have a look, and make sure that the code is an accurate reproduction.

Your HTML is invalid. You have a </input> tag which makes it invalid.

You can easily center them horizontally because the elements have a defined width and have position applied. By setting the left and right properties to 0 and applying margin: auto on the horizontal axis, they will align perfectly in the center.
Another option would be to place the elements in a more modern grid or flex layout and use the according properties to center them. But I expect you would have to alter the html structure a bit to make this work.


#F {
  transform: translate(0%, 2%);
}

#border {
  transform: translate(0%, -2%);
}

body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-open-button {
  /* horizontally centered: */
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

  top: 84vh;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1vh solid #9D9E99;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
  transition: transform ease-out 200ms;
  transition: transform ease-out 200ms, -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
}

.menu-open-button:hover {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background: #379;
  border: 1vh solid #FFFFFF;
}

.menu-open-button:hover .lines {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu-open {
  display: none;
}

.lines {
  width: 5vh;
  height: 0.7vh;
  background: #9D9E99;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -2.4vh;
  margin-top: -0.3vh;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
  transition: transform 200ms;
  transition: transform 200ms, -webkit-transform 200ms;
}

.line-1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -1.7vh, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -1.7vh, 0);
}

.line-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.line-3 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1.7vh, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 1.7vh, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button .line-1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button .line-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button .line-3 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu-open-button {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

.menu-open-button:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  border-color: transparent;
}

.cssplay-menu {
  /* horizontally centered: */
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

  top: 50vh;
  width: 40vh;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transform: translateX(-850%) z-index:1;
}

.hover {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  left: 45vw;
  margin-top: 84vh;
  position: fixed;
}

.hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #379;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-out, background-color 0.5s ease-out, top 0.5s ease-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

#menu-open:checked~.hover::before {
  top: -600%;
  transform: scale(3500);
  /* Увеличивает круг, чтобы он покрывал экран */
  background-color: #379;
}

.cssplay-menu .holder {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  max-width: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  --mask: radial-gradient(#0000 34.65%, #ffff 34.95% 67.5%, #0000 67.8% 69.5%, #ffff 69.7%);
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask) no-repeat;
  mask: var(--mask) no-repeat;
  mask-position: 0 20vh;
  mask-size: 100% auto;
}

.cssplay-menu input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.cssplay-menu .segment {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  margin-left: -48%;
  margin-top: -48%;
  width: 96%;
  height: 96%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 2.4, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.menu-open:checked~.segment {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.cssplay-menu .curve-upper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  top: 1%;
  width: 98%;
  height: 98%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0s;
}

.cssplay-menu .curve-lower {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(-240deg) scale(0);
  transition: 0s;
}

.cssplay-menu .curve {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #8b0000;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(60deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #008080;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  transition: 0.25s ease;
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(-230deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(-200deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(-170deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotate(-140deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotate(-110deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) skewY(60deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(7) {
  transform: rotate(100deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(8) {
  transform: rotate(140deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(9) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .center {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -20%;
  margin-top: -20%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #8b0000;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu .holder .segment {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu .holder .center {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu .holder .curve-upper {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu .holder .curve-lower {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform: rotate(-240deg) scale(1);
}

.cssplay-menu #c1:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(1),
.cssplay-menu #c2:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(2),
.cssplay-menu #c3:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(3),
.cssplay-menu #c4:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(4),
.cssplay-menu #c5:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(5),
.cssplay-menu #c6:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(6),
.cssplay-menu #c7:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(7),
.cssplay-menu #c8:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(8),
.cssplay-menu #c9:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(9) {
  background: #eb8c00;
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu #c2:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-210deg)
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu #c3:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-180deg)
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu #c4:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-150deg)
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu #c5:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-120deg)
}

body[data-or-condition="1"] {
  #M0 {
    height: 300vh !important;
  }
  .cssplay-menu {
    transform: translate(0%, 252%);
    z-index: 4;
  }
  .menu-open-button {
    transform: translate(0%, 830%);
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .hover {
    margin-top: 180vh;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  #menu-open:checked~.hover::before {
    top: 300%;
  }
  .menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate(0%, 1030%);
    transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate(0%, 1030%);
    transition: 0 ease;
  }
  .p1 {
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translate(-3%, 102%);
  }
  .p2 {
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translate(-3.5%, 140%);
  }
  .p3 {
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translate(-4%, 190%);
  }
  g[id="p2"] {
    display: none;
  }
  g[id="p3"] {
    display: none;
  }
  g[id="border"] {
    display: none;
  }
}
<html>

<head>
  <title>Techonology</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body class="no-scroll" id="TL" style="" data-or-condition="0">
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background: #379;">

    <div id="M0" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open" id="menu-open"></input>
        <label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
        <span class="lines line-1"></span>
        <span class="lines line-2"></span>
        <span class="lines line-3"></span>
    </label>
        <label class="hover"></label>
        <div class="cssplay-menu">
          <div>
            <input type="radio" id="c1" name="segment" checked="checked">
            <input type="radio" id="c2" name="segment">
            <input type="radio" id="c3" name="segment">
            <input type="radio" id="c4" name="segment">
            <input type="radio" id="c5" name="segment">
            <input type="checkbox" id="c6" onclick="checkConditions()">
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" checked="checked">
            <div class="holder">
              <div class="segment">
                <label for="c1"><span></span></label>
                <label for="c2"><span></span></label>
                <label for="c3"><span></span></label>
                <label for="c4"><span></span></label>
                <label for="c5"><span></span></label>
                <label for="c6"><span></span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="curve-lower">
                <div class="curve"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <svg id="M1" class="page_1" version="1.1" height="100vh" width="100vw" viewBox="0 0 1280 960">
        <g id="F">
                <g id="border">
                    <path d="M1 1 l0 950 l2 -2 l0 -946 l1270 0 l2 -2 Z" fill="#9DAACA" id="3DB"></path>
                    <path d="M1275 951 l0 -950 l-2 2 l0 946 l-1270 0 l-2 2 Z" fill="#6A7489" id="3DS"></path>
                </g>
        </g>        
 </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




I guess the problem was mixing the units, especially cssplay-menu left is set to 42.5vw
I changed that to 50% (or 50vw would work too)
then in the transformation you need to move it to left for half it's width.
Although when I did that it seemed a little off so I changed to it to 58% to look centered.
Check the code below, see if its showing the result you were trying to acheive.


#F {
  transform: translate(0%, 2%);
}

#border {
  transform: translate(0%, -2%);
}

body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-open-button {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1vh solid #9D9E99;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  left: 50%;
  top: 84vh;
  position: fixed;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
  transition: transform ease-out 200ms;
  transition: transform ease-out 200ms, -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
}

.menu-open-button:hover {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background: #379;
  border: 1vh solid #FFFFFF;
}

.menu-open-button:hover .lines {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu-open {
  display: none;
}

.lines {
  width: 5vh;
  height: 0.7vh;
  background: #9D9E99;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -2.4vh;
  margin-top: -0.3vh;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
  transition: transform 200ms;
  transition: transform 200ms, -webkit-transform 200ms;
}

.line-1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -1.7vh, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -1.7vh, 0);
}

.line-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.line-3 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 1.7vh, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 1.7vh, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button .line-1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button .line-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button .line-3 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu-open-button {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

.menu-open-button:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(-58%, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(-58%, 0, 0);
  border-color: transparent;
}

.cssplay-menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50vh;
  width: 40vh;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index:1;
}

.hover {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
  left: 45vw;
  margin-top: 84vh;
  position: fixed;
}

.hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #379;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-out, background-color 0.5s ease-out, top 0.5s ease-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

#menu-open:checked~.hover::before {
  top: -600%;
  transform: scale(3500);
  /* Увеличивает круг, чтобы он покрывал экран */
  background-color: #379;
}

.cssplay-menu .holder {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  max-width: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  --mask: radial-gradient(#0000 34.65%, #ffff 34.95% 67.5%, #0000 67.8% 69.5%, #ffff 69.7%);
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask) no-repeat;
  mask: var(--mask) no-repeat;
  mask-position: 0 20vh;
  mask-size: 100% auto;
}

.cssplay-menu input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.cssplay-menu .segment {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  margin-left: -48%;
  margin-top: -48%;
  width: 96%;
  height: 96%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 2.4, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.menu-open:checked~.segment {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.cssplay-menu .curve-upper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  top: 1%;
  width: 98%;
  height: 98%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0s;
}

.cssplay-menu .curve-lower {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(-240deg) scale(0);
  transition: 0s;
}

.cssplay-menu .curve {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #8b0000;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(60deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #008080;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
  transition: 0.25s ease;
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(-230deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(-200deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(-170deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotate(-140deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotate(-110deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) skewY(60deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(7) {
  transform: rotate(100deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(8) {
  transform: rotate(140deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .segment label:nth-of-type(9) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(50deg);
}

.cssplay-menu .center {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -20%;
  margin-top: -20%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #8b0000;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu .holder .segment {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu .holder .center {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu .holder .curve-upper {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu .holder .curve-lower {
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.58, 3, 0.5, 0.5);
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform: rotate(-240deg) scale(1);
}

.cssplay-menu #c1:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(1),
.cssplay-menu #c2:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(2),
.cssplay-menu #c3:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(3),
.cssplay-menu #c4:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(4),
.cssplay-menu #c5:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(5),
.cssplay-menu #c6:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(6),
.cssplay-menu #c7:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(7),
.cssplay-menu #c8:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(8),
.cssplay-menu #c9:checked~.holder .segment label:nth-of-type(9) {
  background: #eb8c00;
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu #c2:checked~#toggle:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-210deg)
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu #c3:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-180deg)
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu #c4:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-150deg)
}

.menu-open:checked~.cssplay-menu #c5:checked~.holder .curve-lower {
  transform: rotate(-120deg)
}

body[data-or-condition="1"] {
  #M0 {
    height: 300vh !important;
  }
  .cssplay-menu {
    transform: translate(0%, 252%);
    z-index: 4;
  }
  .menu-open-button {
    transform: translate(0%, 830%);
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .hover {
    margin-top: 180vh;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  #menu-open:checked~.hover::before {
    top: 300%;
  }
  .menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate(0%, 1030%);
    transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate(0%, 1030%);
    transition: 0 ease;
  }
  .p1 {
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translate(-3%, 102%);
  }
  .p2 {
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translate(-3.5%, 140%);
  }
  .p3 {
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translate(-4%, 190%);
  }
  g[id="p2"] {
    display: none;
  }
  g[id="p3"] {
    display: none;
  }
  g[id="border"] {
    display: none;
  }
}
<html>

<head>
  <title>Techonology</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body class="no-scroll" id="TL" style="" data-or-condition="0">
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background: #379;">

    <div id="M0" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open" id="menu-open"></input>
        <label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
        <span class="lines line-1"></span>
        <span class="lines line-2"></span>
        <span class="lines line-3"></span>
    </label>
        <label class="hover"></label>
        <div class="cssplay-menu">
          <div>
            <input type="radio" id="c1" name="segment" checked="checked">
            <input type="radio" id="c2" name="segment">
            <input type="radio" id="c3" name="segment">
            <input type="radio" id="c4" name="segment">
            <input type="radio" id="c5" name="segment">
            <input type="checkbox" id="c6" onclick="checkConditions()">
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" checked="checked">
            <div class="holder">
              <div class="segment">
                <label for="c1"><span></span></label>
                <label for="c2"><span></span></label>
                <label for="c3"><span></span></label>
                <label for="c4"><span></span></label>
                <label for="c5"><span></span></label>
                <label for="c6"><span></span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="curve-lower">
                <div class="curve"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <svg id="M1" class="page_1" version="1.1" height="100vh" width="100vw" viewBox="0 0 1280 960">
        <g id="F">
                <g id="border">
                    <path d="M1 1 l0 950 l2 -2 l0 -946 l1270 0 l2 -2 Z" fill="#9DAACA" id="3DB"></path>
                    <path d="M1275 951 l0 -950 l-2 2 l0 946 l-1270 0 l-2 2 Z" fill="#6A7489" id="3DS"></path>
                </g>
        </g>        
 </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



